# Won't Show PDF with Letters in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, errors

I'm trying to compile and view a document in which I put letters into math mode: `$n = 1$`
But whenever I do this, a message comes up that the file cannot be found.
As soon as I edit the document to have no letters in math mode, it compiles and I can view it just fine.
Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm} 
\usepackage{amssymb, latexsym} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Abstract} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item {We will show that the second player has the advantage if $ k = 1$.} 
\vspace{8pt} 
\pause 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  we really need more information.  please provide a small example file, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that gives the result you describe.  then we will be able to experiment to find out why this is happening.

Comment: Sure, sorry:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb, latexsym}
    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Abstract}

    \begin{itemize}

    \item{We will show that the second player has the advantage if $ k = 1$.}

    \vspace{8pt}

    \pause

    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}

    \end{document}

Comment: jenny -- you can always edit your own question.  code doesn't behave well in comments, so updating a question to put the code there is much more effective.

Comment: the default font for `beamer` is sans serif.  in the output, the *k* is sloped -- that is how the math fonts have been set up for `beamer`.  but that's not actually what you ask -- your question says that some file cannot be found.  which file?  (i believe all the packages you ask for are in the basic collection, so they should all be found.)  what distribution are you using, and on what operating system?

Comment: Perhaps you have problems with a font. Show the log-file of your example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain this very well. I was very stressed about the situation and didn't quite think the post through! :/
When I just have numbers in math mode, the PDF works perfectly, and I have a copy of the PDF file in my folder. However, as soon as I add a letter to the math mode, the PDF file disappears. Adobe tells me that the file cannot be found.

Comment: @Jenny Do you get any error messages in the .log file? And how are you compiling? pdflatex or with something else?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing any error messages in the .log file. And I'm compiling and viewing everything by just using control+shift+f5.

Comment: The first line in the `.log` file tells you the TeX compiler and the TeX format used to compile the document. Example: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.5)`